# git ignores .gitignore and commits everything in repository

Tags: git

I created a repository with a .gitignore file. I added this lines to that files

```
log/
*.log
```

I added log directory and run git status
[image]

There is a files named "dev.log" that I changed. Git tracks still the files in log directory. I tried to run `git rm --cached -rf .` but nothing changed.

Comment: Save `.gitignore` as ascii or utf-8.

Comment: You still have to `add` and `commit` this to save the fact that you have removed those files. *After* that the `.gitignore` will take effect. Have you tried `git status --ignored`?

Comment: Yes. I know that I have to use those commands. I didn't use git status --ignored. The first comment solved the problem.